# Spring-data-rest Self Describing Entity

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have been working with spring-data-rest and repositories. Since RESTful apis are supposed to be self-describing, how would you find out the properties of an resource? Is this possible w/o an API document or some special coding?

Person/People example... if there were no people in the repository how could I find out what one looks like? Perhaps there is a url that asks the service to describe the properties of a Person, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: For example, if there is a person you can get           `$ curl http://localhost:8080/people/1
{
  "firstName" : "Frodo",
  "lastName" : "Baggins",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/1"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: But in the case where persons exist then how can I get the service to describe the properties of the resource/entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service can deliver a resource in one or more media types. A client has to understand the media type beforehand. If the media type was jpeg you wouldn't expect the service to deliver a description of the jpeg file format and compression algorithm, would you? It's just the same with a person media type. A person may even be represented with more than one media type. How would a description of a binary format look like?

The APIs should be discoverable, yes, but what a resource looks like is implied by a media type and must be known to a client.

Of course, you could always create a service, that returns some kind of description, but that's not part of REST.

Having said that, depending on the media type there are some standards for descriptions. XML even is kind of based on such standards. It offers either XSD or DTD. For JSON there is at least one draft for an official standard: JSON Schema. More information can be found on [http://json-schema.org](http://json-schema.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I could extend the standard pattern so that a particular url (or query param) would return a description of the "type". The idea is that you could even create tooling to make the consumption of the service easy (create javascript class or something).

Comment: I was hoping that someone is promoting a standard format/layout for such a description.

Comment: @Mark.ewd I updated my answer and added some standards. In the software section of the JSON Schema website you find supporting tools and libraries.